# How to delete an item from an array from localstorage onclick

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

I have the following code. It stores the info on localstorage each time the user clicks on an "add to cart" button:

```
let addCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('product-description-add')
for (let i = 0; i < addCartItemButtons.length; i++){
    let button = addCartItemButtons[i]
    button.addEventListener('click', addProduct)
} 

function addProduct(event) {
    let buttonClicked = event.target
    let getTitle = buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('.product-title').innerText
    let getImage = buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('.product-header img').src
    let getColor = buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('.product-description-text li span').innerText
    let getSize = buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('.product-description-text li select').value
    let getPrice = buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('.product-description-price').innerText
    let getSpan = buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('li span').getAttribute('id')

    let oldItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('newProduct')) || [];
    let newItem = {
        'title': getTitle,
        'image': getImage,
        'color': getColor,
        'size': getSize,
        'price': getPrice,
        'spanid': getSpan,
    };
    
    oldItems.push(newItem);
    localStorage.setItem('newProduct', JSON.stringify(oldItems));
}
```

Then, i have a code that allows me to display the data the user have locally stored by creating divs and displaying the info:

```
let cartProducts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("newProduct"))
for(let i = 0; i < cartProducts.length; i++){
    let newCartProduct = document.createElement('div')
    newCartProduct.classList.add('product')
    newCartProduct.classList.add('cart')
    const image = cartProducts[i].image
    const title = cartProducts[i].title
    const spanid = cartProducts[i].spanid
    const color = cartProducts[i].color
    const size = cartProducts[i].size
    const price = cartProducts[i].price
    let newCartProductContent = `
    <div class="product-header cart"><img src="${image}" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="product-content">
            <h3 class="product-title" id="product-title">
            ${title} 
            </h3>
            <div class="product-description">
                <ul class="product-description-text cart">
                    <li>Color: <span id="${spanid}">${color} </span></li>
                    <li>Size: ${size} </li>
                    <li>Quantity: <input type="number" class="product-description-quantity" min="1" placeholder="2" value="2"></li>
                </ul>
                <p class="product-description-price" id="price1">
                ${price} 
                </p>
                **<a href="#" class="product-description-add cart-remove">Remove<i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>**
            </div>
        </div>`
    newCartProduct.innerHTML = newCartProductContent
    let cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('products_container_first-row')[0]
    cartItems.append(newCartProduct)
}
```

So what i need to do now is to create a function that allows me to delete the data that it's the same which is on localstorage, each time that the user clicks on a "remove" button (in the above code is the line which has the ** ** at beginning and ending), but i cant figure out how to do this. Any ideas? Thanks!

UPDATE: i've come to this code but i get -1 as index for each element:

```
let addCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('product-description-add')
for (let i = 0; i < addCartItemButtons.length; i++){
    let button = addCartItemButtons[i]
    button.addEventListener('click', function(event){
        let buttonClicked = event.target
        let getTitle = buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('.product-title').innerText
        let getImage = buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('.product-header img').src
        console.log(getImage)
        let getColor = buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('.product-description-text li span').innerText
        let getSize = buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('.product-description-text li select').value
        let getPrice = buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('.product-description-price').innerText
        let getSpan = buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('li span').getAttribute('id')
        console.log(getSpan)
    
        let oldItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('newProduct')) || [];
        let newItem = {
            'id': i+1,
            'title': getTitle,
            'image': getImage,
            'color': getColor,
            'size': getSize,
            'price': getPrice,
            'spanid': getSpan,
        };
        
        oldItems.push(newItem);
        localStorage.setItem('newProduct', JSON.stringify(oldItems));
    })
} 

let cartProducts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("newProduct"));
for(let i = 0; i < cartProducts.length; i++){
    let newCartProduct = document.createElement('div')
    newCartProduct.classList.add('product')
    newCartProduct.classList.add('cart')
    console.log(newCartProduct)
    const id = cartProducts[i].id
    const image = cartProducts[i].image
    const title = cartProducts[i].title
    const spanid = cartProducts[i].spanid
    const color = cartProducts[i].color
    const size = cartProducts[i].size
    const price = cartProducts[i].price
    let newCartProductContent = `
    <div class="product-header cart" id="${id}"><img src="${image}" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="product-content">
            <h3 class="product-title" id="product-title">
            ${title} 
            </h3>
            <div class="product-description">
                <ul class="product-description-text cart">
                    <li>Color: <span id="${spanid}">${color} </span></li>
                    <li>Size: ${size} </li>
                    <li>Quantity: <input type="number" class="product-description-quantity" min="1" placeholder="2" value="2"></li>
                </ul>
                <p class="product-description-price">
                ${price} 
                </p>
                <a href="#" onclick="lsdel(\'newProduct\',\'+cartProducts[i].id+\');" class="product-description-add cart-remove">Remove<i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>`
    newCartProduct.innerHTML = newCartProductContent
    let cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('products_container_first-row')[0]
    cartItems.append(newCartProduct)
}
function lsdel(storage_name, value){
    if (localStorage.getItem(storage_name) === null) { 
    } else {        
        var ls_data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storage_name));
        var index   = ls_data.indexOf(value);
        console.log("selected index:"+index);
        if(index == -1){
        // if not matched selected index    
        } else {
            // is matched, remove...
            ls_data.splice(index, 1);
            localStorage.setItem(storage_name, JSON.stringify(ls_data));
            console.log(ls_data);  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the array from local storage, find the index of the matching element with `array.findIndex()`, use `array.splice()` to remove it, then write the array back to local storage.

Comment: is `spanid` the ID of the product? If so, why is it only on the span tag around color?

Comment: @Kinglish no, the spanid is one element i needed to be stored on localstorage to allow me to style the div when i display it to the user, but it's no related to the product id

Comment: thanks @Barmar i'll try to do it

Comment: You can also use `array.filter` with the predicate that excludes the item you want to remove and then save the filtered array.

Comment: I guess my question was more: where is the ID for each product? You should track it in your arrays of selected products and use it in your HTML in some way. When someone adds an item, make the id part of the data saved. When someone deltes an item, you can use the id to find the saved item and remove it.

Comment: @Kinglish oh i get it, but how should i save the ID? bc i need each product to have a different one so i can't write it on the html element

Comment: You can do something like `<div class="product-header cart" data-prodid="12345">` - and in your save array... `let newItem = {
       id: event.target.closest('.product-data-cart').dataset.prodid,  'title': getTitle, ...` then you can delete it with something like `document.querySelector('[data-prodid=' + ID + ']').remove()` etc

Comment: @Barmar hey i've been doing what you told me and i got a new problem, the index i always get is '-1' in any of elements, how can i fix this? bc then the function i made is working fine

Comment: Either you're not getting the array from local storage correctly, or the filter function is wrong.

Comment: Update the question with the code you tried.

Comment: @Barmar updated!

Comment: @Barmar the function works properly when i change the condition "if (index==-1)" bc i tried it, the problem with doing that is that removes the last element of the array instead of the one i'm clicking :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`value` is the ID of an element, but `ls_data` is an array of objects, not IDs. So `ls_data.indexOf(value)` will not find the object in the array. And even if `value` were an object, this wouldn't work because object equality is based on identical objects in memory, not comparing contents.

You need to use `findIndex` to match the `id` property of an array element.

```js
function lsdel(storage_name, value) {
  if (localStorage.getItem(storage_name) === null) {} else {
    var ls_data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storage_name));
    var index = ls_data.findIndex(({id}) => id == value);
    console.log("selected index:" + index);
    if (index == -1) {
      // if not matched selected index    
    } else {
      // is matched, remove...
      ls_data.splice(index, 1);
      localStorage.setItem(storage_name, JSON.stringify(ls_data));
      console.log(ls_data);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I can't manage to make it work properly, the index keeps on being '-1' each time i click on the remove button. Your code i'm sure that works perfectly but the problem must be something that i'm not being able to identify and resolve :||

Comment: `addProduct()` isn't putting the `id` into `newItem`.

Comment: No, the id is being added to newItem, this is an example of an element of the array stored on localstorage: 0: {id: 1, title: "Adidas Hoodie", image: "http://**/img/products/1.jpg", color: "gray",…}
color: "gray"
id: 1
image: "http://**/img/products/1.jpg"
price: "$39.99"
size: "M"
spanid: "sp1"
title: "Adidas Hoodie" but index is still -1 :@

Comment: `let newItem = {
        'title': getTitle,
        'image': getImage,
        'color': getColor,
        'size': getSize,
        'price': getPrice,
        'spanid': getSpan,
    };` where is the `id` in that?

Comment: I'm looking at the code in `function addProduct(event)`.

Comment: In the update i added the code where i pass the id to the function: let newItem = {
            'id': i+1,
            'title': getTitle,
            'image': getImage,
            'color': getColor,
            'size': getSize,
            'price': getPrice,
            'spanid': getSpan,
        };

Comment: Then I'm not sure what's going wrong. Use `console.log(value)` and `console.log(ls_data)` to make sure that you're getting what you expect.

Comment: Ok i'll try to do that, thanks for your help by the way

Comment: i get it! Finally it works properly, it deletes the element of the array that i'm clicking to remove. but do you know how to refresh the page automatically and show the changes without having to refresh the page?

Comment: Add an ID to the `product_description` DIV, e.g. `id="desc-{$id}`. Then you can do `document.getElementById("desc-"+value).remove()`

Comment: Thanks man, I really appreciate the time you spend here trying to help me